# Is it possible to communicate asp.net to sharepoint to office web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint, ms-office, office365

We are designing an asp.net web project. This project is about electronic document management system.

In our project, We need to view and edit Office documents on your browser. If it is possible , we want to communicate with SharePoint and Office web app from asp.net pages. Asp.net to SharePoint server and then office web app server . (Asp.net can not communicate directly with office web app  because of this we should use SharePoint). The question marks in my head.

1. Can I upload files to SharePoint from the asp.net project?
2. Is it possible that showing in iframe an address from SharePoint
   server to view and edit document on my asp.net web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, yes, you can. You can use the SharePoint Client Object Model to do that. The flowing articles provides some introductions about SCOM:
1. [Using the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-1.aspx)
2. [Shorten Your Backlog: Integrating ASP.NET and SharePoint](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/03/01/Integrating-ASPNET-and-SharePoint.aspx?Page=1)

For question 2, I think it is possible, but I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload a document to a document library from Asp.Net using either JSOM or CSOM.

For the second part, i am not sure if it is possible, i tried it myself using the IFrame option and it didn't appear and showed a message indicating that the source of the iframe must be running inside the same domain.